# How to package React front end with Spring Boot and run the executable jar?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Java Spring Boot back end app containing REST services.  Just inside the main Spring Boot project folder I have a React app for the front end.  I can run the Spring Boot app and successfully access all the end points.  I can run the React app and it works too.  But now I want to create an executable jar file and run that as a single application, not two.

I create an executable fat jar file like this:

```
mvn clean install
```

It creates a jar file.  When I run it with

```
java -jar target/medaverter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

the back end starts up ok but the front end does not pop up in a browser window like it does if I run it separately with

```
npm start
```

I've followed these tutorials to get where I'm at. Apparently I'm missing something.
https://medium.com/@mukundmadhav/build-and-deploy-react-app-with-spring-boot-and-mysql-6f888eb0c600#37fa
https://blogg.kantega.no/webapp-with-create-react-app-and-spring-boot/

Here is the pom.xml file.  The plugins section does the magic of merging in the React app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.tekknow</groupId>
    <artifactId>medaverter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>medaverter</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Security</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
               <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.6</version>
               <configuration>
                   <workingDirectory>medaverter-front</workingDirectory>
                   <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>install node and npm</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <nodeVersion>v8.9.4</nodeVersion>
                           <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
                   <execution>
                       <id>npm install</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>npm</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <arguments>install</arguments>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
                   <execution>
                       <id>npm run build</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>npm</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <arguments>run build</arguments>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/medaverter-front/build"/>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-antrun-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.8,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have verified that the same files that are in the react folder, called medaverter-front, get copied over to the target/classes/public folder.

I have the following proxy set in my package.json file:

```
  "proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "ws": true
    }
  },
```

If I enter into a browser:
http://localhost:8080/api/test/all

I see in the browser:
"Public Content"

as I should if I were accessing the back end directly, but the terminal shows:

> n.t.m.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt     : Unauthorized error: Full
>   authentication is required to access this resource

If I enter into the browser:
http://localhost:8080/home

it returns "There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401)."

Clearly Spring Security JWT is interfering somehow but I just can't figure it out.  The home page does not require any authentication, yet something is acting like it does.  Here is the backend tree:
[image]

I should also mention that during app startup, I see several of these Exceptions:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is
>   not allowed

But that doesn't stop it from running.  I solved that problem by adding "&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" to the spring.datasource.url in application.properties file.

Comment: try removing dependency spring-boot-starter-security for confirmation , without the proper configuration spring security might try to secure all urls.

Comment: good idea.  I tried it but then build failed with 81 errors.

Comment: try this https://github.com/sachin073/spring-security, this is also a spring security demo app with embedded JSP as front end in jar itself. Your issue is security related. try taking reference for security config.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I cloned the project and see it's a gradle project.  I've never used gradle.  I installed gradle and tried to build your project with "gradlew build" but it failed with "Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-security-config"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.  I added

```
    .antMatchers("/home/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

to the configure method in the WebSecurityConfig.java file.  It now looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/home/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

I was confused about this method (and still am).  I had thought that if /api/test/all was handled, that was all I needed.  Apparently not.  Why did I think that?  The React flow starts at App.js which contains

```
      <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]} component={Home} />
```

home.component.js contains:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    UserService.getPublicContent().then(
      response => {
        this.setState({
          content: response.data
        });
      },
```

user.service.js contains:

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/test/';

class UserService {
  getPublicContent() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + 'all');
  }
```

The SpringBoot TestController.java handles the backend calls:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String allAccess() {
        return "Public Content.";
    }
```

Hence, / or /home ultimately calls http://localhost:8080/api/test/all which returns "Public Content".